# Integration Simple-form 2.0.0 and Zurb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, zurb-foundation

In the new simple_form gem ( 2.0.0 ), there are a wrapper to twitter. But I prefer using zurb-foundation. So I try create this wrapper.

Anyone has some input to create the wrapper ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the following lines in `/config/initializers/simple_form.rb`:

```
config.wrappers :default, :class => :input,
   :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|

...

b.use :hint, :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :hint }
b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :error }

...

config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-error'
```

for

```
config.wrappers :default, :class => :input,
   :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :errors do |b|

...

b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :small }

...

# delete hint
config.error_notification_class = 'alert-box alert'
```

You can see the [diff here](https://github.com/naoisegolden/divebook/commit/139e2d1df00381a9a381c5649540612d4f3f533f).

Comment: Thanks! But there's a minor error on line 2. It should be `:error_class => :error` (singular).

Answer (score 3):

This [wiki entry](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Zurb%27s-Foundation-integration) gets you close. Then you can edit the button classes and error class to match simple_form's class structure.

Comment: I know but it's to simple_form 1.5, not 2.0